# Bootstrap navbar menu item li a change the active class when in the specific page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using pure CSS and some javascript, how can I manage to remove and add the class 'active' to my li item? I tried using the 'onclick' function in javascript. It changes the color of the item but it doesn't redirect me to the link of my the selected item.

```
<div class="main_navs">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php" class="main_navmenu active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.php" class="main_navmenu">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php" class="main_navmenu">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="account.php"> Wishlist</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php"> Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="gift_card.php"> Gift Card</a></li>
        <li><a href="cart.php" class="main_navmenu"
           <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart <span class="badge">0</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#main_menu_items li a').on('click', function(){
          $('li a.active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
     });
 </script>
```

CSS:

```
     .main_navs ul li a.active{
          background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
          color: #333;
     }
     .main_navs ul li a{
          background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
          color: #fff;
     }
```

Comment: Is there any other scrpt over-riding the onclick function by preventing default action?

Comment: your `<a ` anchor is not closed for Cart 0

Comment: there's no other script - Praveen Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you out. It should add the class active to the matching anchor in your menu on page load.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");
    $('.main_navs a').each(function() {
        if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove trailing slash first and then it would equal to the url that you want to match.

My solution is:

```
var current = window.location.href;
  var current_url = current.replace(/\/$/, "");
  $('.navbar-nav a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // if the current path is like this link, make it active
    if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current_url) !== -1){
      $this.addClass('active');
    }
  });
```